# getting local user token for a social account user

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am using the django-oauth-toolkit to act as my own oauth2 provider. allauth for all the authentication. On top of that is rest-auth, which provides rest interfaces for both.

My users have the option to login/register via another social account provider (such as facebook etc.)

I register the users via [/rest-auth/facebook/ POST containing the authentication toke](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#social-authentication-optional)n of (lets stay with the example) facebook.

In return I get some Token which is not the oauth2 token I need. 
How can I get my oauth2 token?

Comment: Could you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. 
It was harder than I thought, tracing down rest-auth and allauth until I came to this solution:

Basically, I merged the TemplateView from the django oauth toolkit with the LoginView from rest-auth. Then instead of storing a [rest-framework Authentication Token](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) I create a BearerToken and return it.

[Github-Commit of the solution](https://github.com/Unic8/django-rest-api-template/commit/7322d0d1fe2b7edec02947829c235bfb95a1e7a5)